# PHP - Can I use a function for an equation in this if statement?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I have an alarm system that I want to run, but depending on the statistic, it needs to alarm for greater than or less than the stat for this time last week.  The if statement is simply:

```
if ((($past / 100) * 75) > $present)
```

But I need to flip the greaterthan to a lessthan on certain conditions.  Is a function the best way to do this?  I can't quite get my head around how they work in this regard.   An example would be good, all I can find are generic print functions etc

Comment: I think your if statement can be written as `if (
    (!$certain_condition && ($past / 100 * 75) > $present)
    || ($certain_condition && ($past / 100 * 75) < $present)
) ` given that the result of _certain conditions_ can be stored in a variable, `$certain_condition`

Comment: @Ejay that's very elegant, deserves to be an answer, not a comment

Comment: @Ejay - please make your comment an answer. You deserve it! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your if statement can be written as

```
if ( 
    (!$certain_condition && ($past / 100 * 75) > $present) 
    || ($certain_condition && ($past / 100 * 75) < $present) 
)
```

given that the result of *certain conditions* can be stored in a variable, `$certain_condition`

Comment: Thanks Ejay, this was the most elegant way to do things by far.  But thanks everyone for the other answers too, I was really twisting my brain, and the explanations really helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
function compare($a,$b,$operator)
{
 if($operator==">")
   {
    return ($a>$b);
   }
 else if($operator=="<")
   {
    return ($a<$b);
   }
}
```

To check if its Greater

```
if (compare(($past / 100) * 75),$present,">") 
{

}
```

To check if its Smaller

```
if (compare(($past / 100) * 75),$present,"<") 
{

}
```

Comment: the function seems to me like "overkill" ?

Comment: Could be, but that's what they asked for `PHP - Can I use a function for an equation in this if statement?`

Comment: nae... "Is a function the best way to do this?" was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a function and feed it the direction you want it to take.

```
function comparison($past, $present, $gt = true){

if($gt){
  return  ( ( ($past / 100) * 75) > $present) ? true : false;
}else{
  return  ( ( ($past / 100) * 75)  <  $present) ? true : false;
}

}

// debug
// var_dump(comparison($past, $present, true));
```

Use it like this - it returns true or false.

```
$past = 100;
$present = 80;

// usage eg
if( comparison($past, $present) ){
// start running some other process in gt> mode

}
```